# How to format a block of text with fixed width in Python?

Tags: python, string-formatting

I'm trying to generate a string which looks like this:

```
Nadya's Cell:  (415) 123-4567
Jim's Cell:    (617) 123-4567
```

where the names and phone numbers vary and need to be interpolated in, and the phone numbers should be aligned. For this example, I've used the following template:

```
name1 = "Nadya"
name2 = "Jim"

phone_number1 = "(415) 123-4567"
phone_number2 = "(617) 123-4567"

string = "{name1}'s Cell:  {phone_number1}\n{name2}'s Cell:    {phone_number2}".format(**locals())
```

Instead of adding the spaces in manually, I'd like the total width of the string to adapt to the longest of `name1` and `name2`.

So far, all I've been able to come up with following https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html is the following:

```
max_length = max(len(name1), len(name2))

# This should use max_length and contain "'s Cell:"
string = "{name1:<7}{phone_number1}\n{name2:<7}{phone_number2}".format(**locals())
print(string)
```

which produces

```
Nadya  (415) 123-4567
Jim    (617) 123-4567
```

The problem is that the total width, `7`, is still hard-coded into the template, and I don't see how to add the `'s Cell:` after the name because this produces spaces between the name and the apostrophe. Any ideas how to tackle this?

Comment: Have you tried replacing your spaces in your first attempt with `\t`? Aligns them for me at least, so: `"{name1}'s Cell:\t{phone_number1}\n{name2}'s Cell:\t{phone_number2}".format(**locals())`

Comment: That assumes the everything in the column fits before the next tab stop. Otherwise, you have to start messing with where the tab stops are actually set, which is terminal-dependent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use nested format specifiers, an often overlooked feature:

```
max_length = max(len(name1), len(name2)) + 2

string = """{name1:<{max_length}}{phone_number1}
{name2:<{max_length}}{phone_number2}""".format(**locals())

print(string)
# output:
# Nadya  (415) 123-4567
# Jim    (617) 123-4567
```

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) only mentions them in passing, which probably explains why they're relatively unknown:

> A format_spec field can also include nested replacement fields within
>   it. These nested replacement fields may contain a field name,
>   conversion flag and format specification, but deeper nesting is not
>   allowed. The replacement fields within the format_spec are substituted
>   before the format_spec string is interpreted. This allows the
>   formatting of a value to be dynamically specified.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution using f-strings, following https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/#format-specifiers:

```
name1 += "'s Cell:"
name2 += "'s Cell:"
max_length = max(len(name1), len(name2))

string = f"{name1:{max_length+2}}{phone_number1}\n{name2:{max_length+2}}{phone_number2}"
print(string)
```

which produces

```
Nadya's Cell:  (415) 123-4567
Jim's Cell:    (617) 123-4567
```

as required.